# I'm able to assume AWS role in Console but not in cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-policies, aws-organizations

I have AWS organization with `users (id: 111111111111)` and `dev (id: 222222222222)` accounts. Users first login to the `users` account, and then able to switch to the `dev` account.

**The problem: Users are able to switch role via console (website), but NOT via the CLI...**

This is how I switch via the CLI:

```
export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" \
$(aws sts assume-role \
--role-arn  arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/administrator  \
--role-session-name TestSessionName \
--query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" \
--output text))
```

And I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/gitlab-ci-user is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/administrator
```

Made sure which user i'm logged in via cli:

```
> aws sts get-caller-identity                                                           
{
    "UserId": "...",
    "Account": "111111111111",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/gitlab-ci-user"
}
```

The user `gitlab-ci-user` is member of the `AdminsDevAssumeRole` group, and the following policy:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/administrator"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

In the `dev account (222222222222)`, I got role `administrator`, with the following trust relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea why i'm not able to switch role via cli (but do in console)?

Comment: You only allow the assume-role when you have NO mfa set??

Comment: @luk2302 wow it works! thought it meant "ignore mfa". Dont believe i wasted two hours on it... (:

Comment: @luk2302 if you want, you can post an answer, and i will make as solution